# Autowire object instance in spring shell command?

Tags: java, spring, autowired, spring-shell

I have a small server which was in need of a simple console to enter a commands. After a bit of searching i found spring shell, which does the job.

Some of my commands need access to the server instance object.

How can i (autowire?) my server object instance into my spring shell command so that i can access my server object instance in a spring shell command?

Bootstrap constructor seem to creating the application context and immediately finds the user shell commands.

I tried to use:

```
bootstrap.getApplicationContext().getBeanFactory().registerSingleton(class, myserverinstance)
```

But this can only be done after Bootstrap constructor is called and then it is too late.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand.

First of all, is the Spring Shell process the same process as what is running your "server"?

Regarding wiring, Spring Shell is no different than any other Spring application. I understand that you already have an instance of your "server" bean. The best thing to do in that case is to use a [FactoryBean](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factorybean)

Hope that helps

Comment: I've just implemented your suggestion and it works! I had to create a plain java singleton which holds my server instance so that the factorybean could get the server instance in the getObject() method.